Blank white box or toast in Android?
I have a react native app that I am running through Android studio on my Samsung phone. The app uses many RN npm packages but also has some native code. The MainApplication and MainActivity files are in kotlin but the native modules I wrote are in java. Whenever I login with Google (using react-native-google-signing) or request any permissions, I see this annoying empty white toast-like box at the top of the screen. What is this and how do I make it go away?
I think it is an empty toast generated by the Android OS but I'm not sure. Both chatgpt and claude seem to think I'm stuck with it.

